# Pinging a network share

Tags: network-share

I'm trying to detect network issue on a share drive that I do not have control over.  If it were a PC on the network I would ping it, what can I do to check the status of a network share.  I am working off of a Windows 7 PC.  Is there a ping or traceroute type mechanism for network shares?

Comment: what do you mean by 'check the status' of a share? If you want to see if it's up just go to start and enter \\servername\share to browse to it. If you want to monitor it, there are tools to monitor SMB shares. I use IPMonitor.

Comment: i think there is a x-and-y issue inhere - it is stated, that ping works with a network target while a share requires an existing machine and share to work.... and a ping that has a failure means mostly there is a other issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `net view` to enumerate through available shares on a server.

E.G. `net view \\192.168.1.2\mydirectory\`

However, I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: I've pinged machines on our network and have a few time outs.  I'd like to see if there are any time outs on the share.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A network share is dependant on connectivity to a specific host (with the exception of DFS). So if you lose connectivity with a host, you will lose connectivity to the share by default.

Comment: @MichaelShnitzer I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what ping (ICMP echo) does. Not getting a response from a ping doesn't mean that something is broken. It just means that device doesn't respond to a ping. You can use any number of ways to see if a share is up, but if you don't have access to the server, there's no way to know if something is wrong or if you just don't have access any more.

Answer (score 1):

A "share" is hosted on some piece of hardware - whether that be a NAS or a server or whatever.

So if you normally access the share with `\\SHARE\folder` then just type `ping SHARE` and you're able to ping it.  It's the same principle as pinging another workstation.

Now if you're saying "hey, I can get to `\\SHARE` but accessing `\\SHARE\folder\file` keeps timing out, that is more likely an issue with the folder, the file, or possibly the application you're using to try to access said file.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot connect into the files of the share folder you have to check the security issues (on the folder right click> properties> security and you have to check if your account has the privileges to connect or modify it or not.)

Otherwise you have to check the pc name or IP into run menu (ctrl + R) or into a bar of a folder, that will open pc's shared folders.